# Can someone review this mathematical derivation that in Special Relativity FTL implies Time Travel

Tags: special-relativity, time, causality, time-travel

I am looking to show mathematically (i.e. with derivations and algebraic relationships) that FTL implies time travel. Here's what I got:

Suppose we have 2 ships $O_1, O_2$ traveling at $0.9c$ in opposite directions and originating at a point called $0$ at time $0$.

Suppose now 1 year has passed in the frame of reference $O_2$ where $O_2$ is still. In this frame of reference $O_1$ has been travelling at $ \frac{0.9c + 0.9c}{1 + \frac{0.81c^2}{c^2}} = .9944c $

So according to $O_2$, a total of $(1) \times \sqrt{1 - \frac{(.9944c)^2}{c^2} } $ years have passed on $O_1$'s clocked.

So now suppose $O_2$ instantaneously sends a "visitor" to $O_1$. That visitor when it arrives at $O_1$ finds that year is  $(1) \times \sqrt{1 - \frac{(.9944c)^2}{c^2} } $ in $O_1$ and therefore the year is

$(1) \times \sqrt{1 - \frac{(.9944c)^2}{c^2} }  \sqrt{1 - \frac{(.9944c)^2}{c^2} } $  in $O_2$ (since from $O_1$'s frame of reference O_2 is doing the moving). So if the visitor instantenously teleports back they return to $O_2$ at time $1 - \frac{(.9944c)^2}{c^2} $ years whereas they started at time $1$ years.

Does this capture the essence of the FTL implies time travel argument? I made my life easy by letting the visitor teleport. Suppose I had the visitor travelling at some speed $v >> c$, I can still use some algebra and perhaps elementary calc (since I'm too lazy to do this elegantly) to argue how much time passes on $O_1$ before the visitor arrives (consistent with $O_2$'s interpretation of $O_1$'s clock).

### Why this wasn't answered for me earlier:

I checked:

[Can FTL-Communication between two points in the same frame of reference break causality?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/203708/can-ftl-communication-between-two-points-in-the-same-frame-of-reference-break-ca)

[What spacelike, timelike and lightlike spacetime interval really mean?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/169631/what-spacelike-timelike-and-lightlike-spacetime-interval-really-mean/217805#217805)

[What's the problem with light traveling at speed higher than $c$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/249026/whats-the-problem-with-light-traveling-at-speed-higher-than-c/249029#249029)

with the terms "Special Relativity FTL implies Causality" and really couldn't find a plain and simple mathematical proof.

I came across:

[How does faster than light travel violate causality?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52249/how-does-faster-than-light-travel-violate-causality/191488#191488)

But I couldn't understand the where the accepted answer got their $2796$ from in their last bullet point of the FTL implies Causality thought experiment. So I decided I had no choice but to set it up from scratch myself and have someone comment.

Comment: Please note that [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: That is fair, but there is a conceptual question here in what  I’m asking. Never on the site was a clear, down to the algebra explanation of how faster than light implies time travel given. So I decided to ask based one that. Hence my mention of the links in the second half

Comment: *instantenously teleports*  This immediately looks like a problem as the one thing you can't do in SR or GR is instantaneously travel anywhere.

Comment: So my thought process: you can’t FTL either so I assumed if we break that faster than c travel we might as well, make it into travel that is arbitrarily faster to keep the math simple. If the question suffers substantially from that I’ll edit it to have a body traveling at 10c and re-calculate the numbers. I might have taken too much of a liberty there

Comment: Keeping the maths simple is not the goal.  When the maths is simplified you can't do that by breaking a rule that's so fundamental to the model.